# joomla metadescription not working after repointing with different domain in same host

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I have www.test1.com site and all the things are working fine. I did re pointing the site with www.test2.com. All the content are working fine except meta data. Why its happened I donot know. Please let me lknow any one why meta data is not showing in this site. Joomla version is 3.0

Comment: I changed the live_site='http://www.test2.com' from configuration file. It is working fine.

Comment: Please write this as answer and accept it to mark it as solved ;) Can I also ask that you sometimes ask some question here as the new site is now in Public Beta: http://joomla.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the $live_site='http://www.test2.com'; from configuration.php file. It is working fine.